# CakePhp - How to access the id of the record in validation?

Tags: php, cakephp

To validate the slug, I need to know the value of the `$entity->id`. However, it's only accessible if we directly pass it in `$data`: `$this->Accounts->patchEntity($entity, $data);`.

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {
  $validator
    ->add('slug', [
      'isUnique' => [
        'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
          debug($this);
          debug($value);
          debug($context);
        }
      ]
    ]
}
```

I cannot guarantee, that I will always be passing id in all of my controllers. Is there some way to access the `$entity` in my validation rules?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access `$entity` in your validation.

However, CakePhp has a special api for these validations - [RulesChecker](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/validation.html#applying-application-rules). It should be used for ensuring email uniqueness e.g..
In `buildRules()` method you can access the `$entity`.

> While basic data validation is done when request data is converted into entities, many applications also have more complex validation that should only be applied after basic validation has completed. These types of rules are often referred to as ‘domain rules’ or ‘application rules’. CakePHP exposes this concept through ‘RulesCheckers’ which are applied before entities are persisted.

#### You should add the `buildRules()` method to your table class:

```
// Don't forget the import!
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;

public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules){
    // Add a rule that is applied for create and update operations
    $rules->add(function ($entity, $options) {
        // Return a boolean to indicate pass/failure
    }, 'ruleName');

    // Add a rule for create.
    $rules->addCreate(function ($entity, $options) {
        // Return a boolean to indicate pass/failure
    }, 'ruleName');

    // Add a rule for update
    $rules->addUpdate(function ($entity, $options) {
        // Return a boolean to indicate pass/failure
    }, 'ruleName');

    // Add a rule for the deleting.
    $rules->addDelete(function ($entity, $options) {
        // Return a boolean to indicate pass/failure
    }, 'ruleName');

    return $rules;
}
```